# Foreach loop in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

It works in online PHP compiler but doesn't work on my local. It also doesn't work with other arrays (not only with `$_SERVER`). I see red mark on the right side at the line where `foreach` loop wrote

PhpStorm suggests to write before `foreach` something like:

```
/** @var TYPE_NAME $v */
```

but it also doesn't help at all.

I've tried to turn off all boxes in PHPDoc settings.

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $k => $v){
    echo "$k => $v <br>";
}
```

I expect that `$_SERVER` array prints in browser.

Comment: Have you tried running the code? As in, access it through your browser (and not PHPStorm). There's no syntax-error in that code you posted above, so either PHPStorm is confused, or there is a different syntax-error before that line.

Comment: Yes, I tried, Google Chrome and Firefox gave me a 502 error.
There is no other php code in document (only html)

Comment: So a bad gateway. Then your localhost configuration isn't properly set up. Doesn't mean the code isn't working (that would be a 500 error).

Comment: @Slava 111 I agree with Qirel, just for test try to dump you values with var_dump($_SERVER); die(); and see what it returns.

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) also gave me 502 :(

Comment: Like I said, is likely caused by a bad configuration - which means that it won't reach the part where it executes your PHP code. You need to figure out why you get a 502 first.

Comment: Are you launching the code using built-in web browser (localhost:63342)? If you do - 502 error comes because of it. Try to use an AMP (XAMPP) package as a web server instead. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31859 for details